# Browser show title text which start with multiple spaces as no spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I use AngularJS UI-grid, I want to show a title when I hover with the cursor on the table cell, so I add `tooltip:true` to the gridOptions, if the data starts with multiple spaces, the title is no problem, but when the cursor hovers over the element, the title will ignore the spaces and just text.

I find it is not ui-grid issue.

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justforuse/Ljwjh33L/)

Comment: As what @elfan said, it only shown in Chrome, is there a way to config Chrome performance? not code the title text straightly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the leading space is not shown in Chrome, but shown in other browsers.
To make sure it is shown in Chrome too, try this, add `&zwnj;` (zero-width non-joiner) at the beginning.

```html
<span title = "&zwnj;             data">data</span>
```

Comment: you are right, is there another way to config the chrome performance , not change the title text straightly? thanks.

Comment: not that I know of. It seems that Chrome internal engine does a `trim` on the tooltip before displaying it, which will remove all leading and trailing spaces. `&zwnj;` is not a space so it will not get removed.

Answer (score 1):

use `&nbsp;` before the text - 
anyways not sure what you exactly trying to achieve but I think you are adding the space at wrong place. -

```
`<span title = "    data">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;data</span>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
<span title = "&#8204;      data">data</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dderv88x/